# rsyslog | Queue overflow: 4789 events lost

Tags: rsyslog

I have the following configuration in my rsyslog.conf and I have increased the nodes that send logs to the server, and now I can see this type of message below in the logs:

```
2023-05-23T13:09:32+01:00 xxx [][evtlog][warn] Queue overflow: 63359 events lost
```

rsyslog.conf

```
$umask 0000
$FileCreateMode 0776
$FileOwner eai1

$template PerHostLog,"/app/home/syslogs/%FROMHOST%_%$YEAR%%$MONTH%%$DAY%.log"
if $fromhost-ip != "127.0.0.1" then -?PerHostLog

$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off
$MaxOpenFiles 4096
```

Is there any configuration here that I can prevent to lose messages? or is this related to hardware capacity, network?

Comment: Why do you mean by "increased the nodes that send logs"? - more clients or more queues in rsyslog? And is this log from the client or the server?

Comment: Hi eDonkey, yes, maybe I didn't use the right term, basically, the clients that send logs to the server increased. I had 4 servers sending logs, and now I have 12.

Comment: Okay, do you have an estimate of how many messages are received per minute? And do you know if there are possible connection issues?

Comment: No, I don't have this idea but these logs are related to Web Services and APIs. I would say since we receive 5 million transactions per day (approx), and considering we have more transactions during business hours.

24 * 60 * 60 = 86.400
5.000.000 / 86.400 ≈ 57,87

Maybe, between 100-200 per second...

I don't also think we have connection issues. If we had connection issues, I would see those "events lost" message in the logs

Comment: The amount of logs per second doesn't seem like *that* much. Is this the only active config? If yes, Please look into the [impstats](https://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-impstats/) module. It can provide information on event input, queue size and event forwarding.